# ASP.NET Core Identity - how can I add a new column for Name so it is not stored as a Username?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core Identity. I have a form with a field for Name and a field for Username. However, when I try and save values from the Name field, it complains saying that they are not in Username format. e.g. "John Doe" is not in username format. How can I add a custom column for name so that the AspNetUsers table is altered and stores these values in a separate "Name" column different from the "Username" column?

Steps I have tried so far:

// ApplicationUser.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    
    
    namespace VideoRentalStore.Data
    {
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
            public string Name { get; set; } // Added this new column to the ApplicationUser model.
    
            public string Username { get; set; }
    
            public override string Email { get; set; }
    
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

```
    Ran a new migration: *dotnet ef migrations create "20230216".* No changes were made in the 'migrations' directory.
```

Added a column to the view: Register.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

// New column

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Name"></label> 
        <input asp-for="Input.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Username"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Username" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
        <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" type="password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Register</button>


</form>
```

// Changed the input model and post action in Register.cshtml.cs:

```
public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Name = Input.Name,
            UserName = Input.Username,
            Email = Input.Email
        };
```

A "Name" column is appearing in the database, but it still validates based on Username. I am checking the AspNetUsers table. Any suggestions here - is this the correct table for adding this column?

// User form

[image]

// Invalid user name

[image]

Comment: Do you mind showing the error that you are referring to?

Comment: Can you also show me where you registered your DbContext ?

Comment: Hi @MervynLudick, I am currently receiving this error (screenshot added above for reference): 

SqlException: The column name 'UserName' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to make sure that a column is updated only once. If this statement updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal the duplication in your code.

Comment: Also, my AppIdentityDbContext is in a 'data' folder in the web root. The code is reproduced above.

Comment: What if you rename `Name` property by something else; For instance `FirstName` does it recognize accordingly? In addition, you can implicitly tell about the property while adding migration command like this `Add-Migration "Name"` let's see if that works. The things is, your migration script cannot distinguished name and userName separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using ASP.NET Core Identity. I have a form with a field for Name
> and a field for Username. However, when I try and save values from the
> Name field, it complains saying that they are not in Username format.
> e.g. "John Doe" is not in username format. How can I add a custom
> column for name so that the AspNetUsers table is altered and stores
> these values in a separate "Name" column different from the "Username"
> column?

I have gone through your all description and checked your shared snippet accordingly and reproduced your issue as you can see below:

**Issue Reproduced:**

[image]

**Why The Error For:**

The error you are getting while adding new column "Name" is pretty obvious because if you expand your [IdentityAppDbContextModelSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) under your Migration folder you would seen there is already an "Username" property available as you can see below:

[image]

Therefore, once you are trying to execute your Migration command, it considering your new one with the existing one and throwing the  very error.

**How To Resolve:**

To fix your issue, please follow the steps below:

1. Delete All Files within Migration Folder:

You need to delete your existing migration snapshots and other files within the folder. You can do that as following:

[image]

**Note:** Please remove all the files within Micgration folder.

2. Drop Your Full Identity Project Database:

Once you have deleted your Migration folder, at the same time, you would require to drop your  Identity Project Database as well. You can do that as following:

[image]

**Note:** Find your database and drop or remove it.

3. Rebuild Full Project And Run Migration Command:

After removing your existing Migration and database, please rebuild your full project. Then Execute Migration command and update data as well. It will allow you to append your new proprty without any issue.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Identity model customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0#identity-and-ef-core-migrations) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks. This runs the migration and generates the new column in the database. However,  when I submit the form from the front-end I still get a failed Identity User result - it says "Error - Invalid UserName". Its as if its trying to take the name and use it as the username. See additional screenshots above.

Comment: Edit: I seem to have solved this problem - I changed the code back to 'UserName' from 'User' in Register.cshtml.cs


var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            Name = Input.Name,
            UserName = Input.Username,
            Email = Input.Email
        };

Comment: Thanks for your response and glad to assist on this.